If $(X, A, m)$ is $\sigma$-finite and $B\subseteq A$ is a $\sigma$-sub-algebra, then is $(X, B, \nu)$ $\sigma$-finite?
Here $\nu$ is defined in the following way:
$$\nu(E)= \int_E f dm$$
where $f$ is non-negative, $A$-measureable.
I don't see why we can assert that $\nu$ is also $\sigma$-finite since the subsets of $B$ might not include all the elements of $A$ that create a partition on $X$.

I think additional assumptions on $f$ are needed: $f$ non negative and locally integrability (although in th generality of your setting the later might be hard to define).

I forgot to mention that $f$ is non-negative, I've edited it. However, integrability is left out, which also concerns me.

This need not be the case even if $f \equiv 1$. Say, $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A$ being the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $m$ being the Lebesgue measure, and $B = \{\varnothing, \mathbb{R}\}$. Then $m$ is $\sigma$-finite but $\nu$ is not. (A slightly less trivial example might be $B$ being the $\sigma$-algebra of null and co-null Borel sets.)

An additional observation here: $f$ is very much irrelevant here. As long as $B = A$, $\nu$ would be $\sigma$-finite. Indeed, since $m$ is $\sigma$-finite, we may choose an increasing sequence $A_k \in A$ with $m(A_k) < \infty$ for all $k$ and $\cup_k A_k = X$. Then, for each $(k, l) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, let $A_{k, l} = A_k \cap \{x \in X: f(x) \leq l\}$. We then have $\nu(A_{k, l}) \leq l \cdot m(A_k) < \infty$ and $\cup_{k, l} A_{k, l} = X$, so $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Hence, in the counterexample, the choice of $B$ being a strict $\sigma$-subalgebra of $A$ is necessary.
